# What is the function of (double) C++

Tags: c++, double

I am relevantly new to coding so my question may seem really dull. I was solving a problem and in the suggested solution there was a line that goes:

```
return 4 * (double)nrC / n;
```

where "nrC" and "n" are integers.

What is the function of (double) here. Does it turn "nrC" and "n" into double?

Comment: Look up "what is cast".

Comment: Yes, it's called casting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have mentioned, this is *casting*, that is converting the type of a value.

The reason why it is used here is, that when doing a division with only integers (such as `4/3`), you will get *integer arithmetic*: you loose the remainder (that is `4/3 = 1` (remainer `1` is lost)).

This is sometimes undesirabe. as the results can vary greatly, depending on whether you use integer division or fractional division:

```
 int nrC = 3;
 int n = 2;
 int result_i = 4 * (nrC / n); /* 4*(3/2) = 4*1 = 4 !!! */
 int result_d = 4 * ((double)nrC/n); /* 4*(3.0/2) = 4*1.5 = 6 !!! */
```

Answer (score 2):

It casts (that's the name) the value of `nrC` into a double value. The variable itself is unchanged.